# Motor to rotate gear and hold place when powered down

Tags: motors, solar

I have an application where I need to rotate a solar panel on a moving cart around 2 axes.  The solar panel is medium size (22x25in) and is only 50 watts.  I plan to use an actuator to rotate the panel on axis1 to account for when the sun is high in the sky versus rising or setting. For axis2, I need to be able to rotate the base that the panel rests on by 360 degrees.

For axis2 is there a type of motor that holds its rotational state when powered down even when opposed by some load, similar to an actuator?  An example of the application would be similar to the image below, the red portion.  The blue portion is where I plan to use the actuator.

[image: model]

Comment: Use a worm and gear. But other methods exist. Do a search, water in a bucket and a spring is one… Home Power did an article.

Comment: if you use an equatorial mount, then you only need to use one motor to follow the sun ... the other motor would be used once every few days for only a very small adjustment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Worm gears. The worm (screw) would lay horizontally and drive the spur gears in your photo. Worm gears inherently cannot be back driven so consume no power while holding position. However, they are lossy and noisy when in motion though. If you are not moving the vast majority of the time they are worth it though.
2. You could just use spur gears as drawn with a regular motor or gearmotor (non-worm) and add a electromagnetic spring clutch that is normally locked. If you are moving a lot then that would likely be be better.
3. You could use linear actuators which themselves are motors with built-in worm gears, but the arrangement would be different in that it would be like a hydraulic or pneumatic arm pushing off-center to turn the panels. Will not work if continuous or large amounts of rotation is required so no good for you base.

Comment: For bullet #2 with the clutch, what kind of motor would I use?  A servo I imagine

Comment: You would need position feedback but that need not be part of the motor, especially if you use non 1:1 gearing on your assembly spur gears since motor rotation won't match the assembly rotation. In that case the position sensor goes on the assembly itself, not the motor.

Comment: Would I still use a worm-gear motor?

Comment: You don't need to but no worm means you need a clutch. A worm gear motor would also need the position sensor  on the assembly. It comes down to how much you will need to gear down your motor for torque. If your spur gearing aren't enough on its own then you need a gearmotor of some sort to drive the spur gears, or to replace the spurs with a worm drive altogether. Of course with a worm then no clutch is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Although the size of panel is relatively small, before deciding on the motor (or on the dimensioning of the gears) my advice is to perform a wind load analysis. Those loads tend to become quite high in certain areas. Plus there is the additional problem of  dynamic loading which can really take its toll on the structure and on the gears. Mind you my experience is from 80 to 180 m^2 --850 to 2000 sq.ft-- solar tracker.

Once you have the win loads, then you can determine the Motor (so its very much depended on the location that this will be installed).

Now regarding some details you need to rethink about your project:

- keep in mind that if you use this arrangement in the picture with the spur gears you will need to keep the motor always engaged. This can lead to overheating. So you probably need to add some sort of failsafe locking mechanism. I.e. something that you activate when you want to move (and otherwise its braking).
- Slewing ring or [slewing drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slewing_drive) (which use Worm gears as DKNguyen suggested) are probably the way to go ---if you can afford them -- for the azimuth direction (bottom gear). However, you can probably get away with something cheaper here.
- The elevation direction is probably more demanding. If you plan to build this to sell it, I would strongly advice you not to use the spur gear you have in the image. In a matter of months in moderate weather you will begin to notice wear and tear on the gears. This will increase the wind induced oscillations and produce failure quicker.